# Accessing variables in base class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, getter

Hi this is the header file for my base class Ranger, and in it I have protected variables fov_, usb_ ... that I wish to access with my getter functions, I have three child classes on this one.

Ranger.h

```css
#ifndef RANGER_H
#define RANGER_H

using namespace std;

class Ranger
{
    //private contructor prevents contruction of base class
    Ranger();
public:
    void setBaud(int baud);
    virtual void setFOV(int fov) = 0;
    void setSamp(int sam);
    int getFOV();
    int getBaud();
    int getMaxRange();
    int getUSB();
protected:
    //protected variables that are each indivdualy owned by each sensor
    int fov_;
    int maxRange_;
    int usb_;
    int baud_;
    int samp_;
    double data[];
    //protected contructors for the child classes to use to set fixed parameters
    Ranger(int fov, int maxRange, int port);
    Ranger(int maxRange, int port);
};

#endif // RANGER_H
```

This is my cpp file for the base class that includes the getter files, it just has a return of the portected variables.

```css
Ranger::Ranger()
{

}

Ranger::Ranger(int fov, int maxRange, int port)
{
    fov_ = fov;
    maxRange_ = maxRange;
    usb_ = port;
}

Ranger::Ranger(int maxRange, int port)
{
    maxRange_ = maxRange;
    usb_ = port;
}

void Ranger::setBaud(int baud)
{
    switch(baud)
    {
    case 0: baud_ = 38400; break;
    case 1: baud_ = 115200; break;
    default: baud_ = 38400; break;
    }
}

void Ranger::setSamp(int sam)
{
    samp_ = sam;
}

int Ranger::getFOV()
{
    return fov_;
}

int Ranger::getBaud()
{
    return baud_;
}

int Ranger::getMaxRange()
{
    return maxRange_;
}

int Ranger::getUSB()
{
    return usb_;
}
```

And in my main I want to access the protected variables from the base class to prevent re writting code, so each childs variables are protected in the base class. I try to access these by las.getFOV() but I get a segmentation fault error meaning I don't have access to them, and I don't quite understand why.

main.cpp

```css
int main( int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Laser las;
    int baud;
    cout << "Baud:" << endl;
    cout << "0 - 38400" << endl;
    cout << "1 - 115200" << endl;
    cin >> baud;
    las.setBaud(baud);
    cout << "Baud for Lazer sensor is "+las.getBaud() << endl;
    cout << "Lazer sensor created..." << endl;
    cout << "Lazer's FOV: " + las.getFOV() << endl;
    cout << "Lazer's Max Range: " + las.getMaxRange() << endl;
    cout << "Lazer's Port: " + las.getUSB() << endl;
    Radar rad;
    int baud2;
    cout << "Baud:" << endl;
    cout << "0 - 38400" << endl;
    cout << "1 - 115200" << endl;
    cin >> baud2;
    rad.setBaud(baud2);
    cout << "Baud for Radar sensor is "+rad.getFOV() << endl;
    int fov;
    cout << "Feild of View Of Radar:" << endl;
    cout << "0 - 20 degrees" << endl;
    cout << "1 - 40 degrees" << endl;
    cin >> fov;
    rad.setFOV(fov);
    cout << "FOV is set to " + rad.getFOV() << endl;
    cout << "Radar sensor created..." << endl;
    cout << "Radar's FOV: ' " + rad.getFOV() << endl;
    cout << "Radar's Max Range: " + rad.getMaxRange() << endl;
    cout << "Radar's Port: " + rad.getUSB() << endl;
    Sonar son;
    //rad.setFOV(user);

}
```

and here is one of the child class's cpp file for reference (Lazer)
laser.cpp

```css
#include "laser.h"

Laser::Laser() : Ranger(180,8,0)
{
};

void Laser::setFOV(int fov)
{
    fov_ = fov;
}
```

laser.h

```css
#ifndef LASER_H
#define LASER_H
#include "ranger.h"
#include "rng.h"

class Laser : public Ranger
{
public:
    Laser();
    void setFOV(int fov);
};

#endif // LASER_H
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your getters. The code shown in your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]; as such no authoritative answer is possible, but the likely reason for your crash is your fundamental misunderstanding of what `double data[]` class member is, and you expecting it to be something other than it actually is. Review your C++ book for more information about pointers and arrays.

Comment: `I try to access these by las.getFOV() but I get a segmentation fault error meaning I don't have access to them` - err no. If you didn't have access you'd have a compile time error not a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who commented, I understand I put way too much code to help you guys out, sorry about that I'll know for next time, and thankyou to letting me know the difference between the errors, I've done more research and found that the issue was when I was printing it out you can't use operators like:

```
cout<<""+function()<<endl;
```

Instead you need to separate the functions from the array like so:

```
cout<<""<<function()<<endl;
```

Thanks guys.